# Environment variables from .csh script to perl script

Tags: perl

I am trying to create some automation work and find a requirement to create a perl script that takes  multiple csh scripts to run few testcase. Find below .csh and perl scripts.

xyz.csh script

```
#!/bin/csh

setenv HOME_PATH /home/my_home
echo $HOME_PATH
```

perl script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

system('./xyz.csh');
print "$HOME_PATH"
```

I see no results when I run my perl script. Any solution would help.

perl scripting with csh enironment varibles return to perl script.

Comment: Both Csh and Perl should be avoided as they have lots of problems and their use has decreased to the point that COBOL and FORTRAN are more popular. As @ikegami points out in their answer env vars are private to each process. Env vars are not global. This seems like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What is your real problem?

Comment: First of all, you set `HOME_PATH` in a child process of your Perl process, not in its parent process. Environment variables are inherited from parent to child. Second, you are printing in Perl the Perl-variable `$HOME_PATH`, not the environment variable `HOME_PATH`.  Since you don't describe what exactly you want to achieve, I can't offer much more help.

Comment: Also, I don't understand why you are tagging the question with _shell_; this tag is mostly used for POSIX shells. At least use the _csh_  tag. See the [description of the _shell_ tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shell).

Answer (score 3):

Each process has its own environment, which is completely separate from every others'. A child's environment is usually a copy of its parent's, but they are distinct. A change to one process's environment has no effect on any others.

In this case, the Perl program wants information from the child's process. The child process will need to provide a means for the Perl program to obtain that information. It just so happens the child already does this by outputting the information to stdout. Assuming the value contains no line feed, you could use the following:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $home_path = `./xyz.csh`;
die( "Error spawning `./xyz.csh`: $!\n"                 ) if $? == -1;
die( "`./xyz.csh` killed by signal ".( $? & 0x7F )."\n" ) if $? & 0x7F;
die( "`./xyz.csh` exited with error ".( $? >> 8 )."\n"  ) if $? >> 8;
chomp( $home_path );
```

Comment: As @ikegami knows, his big changes here is from `system`, which send its output wherever your Perl scripts standard output goes, to backticks, which captures the external program's output and gives it back to you so you can store in a variable. See [perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#qx/STRING/).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your situation, but I tend to try to handle these problems by creating env files. If such a file exists (with whatever name you choose to be meaningful), read it in the Perl script to set the env vars. Modules such as [ENV::Util](https://metacpan.org/pod/ENV::Util). That might not work in your case, but may be more useful for the wider world.